# How to convert sql offsetted datetime format back to default?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm offsetting a column for timezone difference. How to convert the returned datetime back to default as now it's being shown with offset information in the column?

```
,SWITCHOFFSET(CAST(CREATEDDATETIME AS datetimeoffset)  
,DATEDIFF(minute, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())) AS CREATEDDATETIMEPDT

2014-07-01 16:44:15.000 2014-07-01 08:44:15.0000000 -08:00
```

Comment: Just to get a clearer idea of your problem, are you trying to get the "local" time relative to the server, or to a user who may be in a different time zone?

Comment: I was converting the UTC to "local" relative to the server. I will explain what I am doing: I have a column that is datetime stored in UTC, I was converting it to datetimeoffset to apply a correction for the local timezone. Now I am in need of converting the adjusted time from datetimeoffset to datetime. Unless there is way to add 8 hours to a datatime column (createddatetime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you have a "local" time converted to a UTC datetime and you want to get back to the local time? This demonstrates one way.

```
select Dateadd(minute,datepart(TZoffset, CREATEDDATETIMEPDT), convert(datetime,CREATEDDATETIMEPDT)) as LocalTime
from
    (select 
        SWITCHOFFSET(   CAST(Getdate() AS datetimeoffset)

                        ,DATEDIFF(minute, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())
                    ) AS CREATEDDATETIMEPDT
    ) UTC
```

To get from a date stored as UTC datetime to local time I think you were pretty close

```
select SWITCHOFFSET( CAST(YourStoredDateTime AS datetimeoffset),DATEDIFF(minute, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())) AS CREATEDDATETIMEPDT
```

and then use dateadd() as I did above.

Comment: The datetime is stored as UTC, I need to display CREATEDATETIME correct to the timezone but in a datetime format and not the datetimeoffset that you see above on CREATEDDATIMEPDT.

Comment: How would I use the dateadd?

Comment: I figured it out! It worked great, I wish I would have learned about dateadd sooner! thanks